# Velocity.js - stopping animation callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, velocity.js

I have this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > ($animate.headline.height() + 100)) {
        $animate.header.velocity({height: "50px"}, { queue: false });
    } else {
        $animate.header.velocity({height: "100px"}, { queue: false });
    }
});
```

If user scrolls xxx pixels from top then animation should start, and that works just fine.

One thing I just noticed and it bothers me - every time I scroll, velocity animation is checking that scrollTop, so overall animation isn't smooth when I'm scrolling, because before animation is triggered function is checking scroll.

Is there any other way to make it smooth?

Example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bIkqF

Comment: Happen to have a minimal example that we can use to view the performance?

Comment: here is example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bIkqF
try to scroll (a lot) when animation is triggered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **throttle** your check with some library like Ben Alman's one : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce/v1.1/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js.

Check this documentation page : http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/.

For your example, you can use it like this :

```
$(window).scroll($.throttle(250, checkTop));

function checkTop() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > ($animate.headline.height() + 100)) {
        $animate.header.velocity({height: "50px"}, { queue: false });
    } else {
        $animate.header.velocity({height: "100px"}, { queue: false });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is completely unnecessary

Comment: @ZachSaucier I don't think so : see my comment on your answer. But I agree that this small plugin can be handwritten as this is simple! BTW, look at the documentation page, this is instructive!

Comment: Can you not link to derelict libraries please? The last time this was updated was on 3/7/2010

Comment: I thought this was for velocity.js, you guys are just using jQuery's scrollTo, not how it would be done with velocity.js, from what I've read in the docs?

Answer (score 3):

Would you prefer a CSS approach instead?

Set your header's css to :

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
```

Add a new class for the desired height:

```
.shrink{
    height:50px;
}
```

And in you js toggle the class :

```
var header = $('.header');
  $(window).on('scroll', function () {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > (header.height() + 20)) {
          header.addClass('shrink');
      } else {
          header.removeClass('shrink');
      }
  });
```

Tinker with the seconds property of transition for a smoother effect.

This way the GPU does the heavy lifting and class toggles performance hit is negligible.
**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u1kq5znd/1)**

Comment: Don't forget to *throttle* your `scroll` handler (cf. http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/ for example, from John Resig - jQuery's creator), this will lead to a better performance again!

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie check the date of the article, While I do agree that you should throttle the scroll handler, in this particular case it is not needed, CSS handles the animation not the JS

Comment: I disagree since : 1. you call many jQuery objects (BTW, you should cache `$(this)` and `$(".header")`) 2. you have some non-negligible treatment in the callback (which is pure-js in addition to the CSS part) 3. there is again some users with old computers / web browsers / ... who needs that sort of optimization too (even though the article is a bit old it is always up to date!!!)

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie Caching the selectors slipped my mind, I ll edit it now cheers on the suggestions. I ll optimize the code now.